# Create a new blob in memory using Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, blob

I want to create a new blob in memory, put the content in the blob, name it, and finally save it as a file in Drive.

I know how to create a file in Drive from blobs.  The only thing I'm looking for is creating the empty new blob to start with.

Comment: You can use the `Utilities` Service:  [Google Documentation - Utilities.newBlob()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#newBlob(Byte))

Comment: Please see my updated answer.  I had answered wrong initially.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a new blob in memory with the Utilities Service:

```
function createNewBlob() {

  var blobNew = Utilities.newBlob("initial data");
  blobNew.setName("BlobTest");

  Logger.log(blobNew.getName());

  blobNew.setDataFromString("Some new Content");

  Logger.log(blobNew.getDataAsString())

  var newFileReference = DriveApp.createFile(blobNew);
  newFileReference.setName('New Blob Test');
};
```

You can also create a new file, with some small amount of data, then change the content.  In this example, a file is created in the root directory with the contents "abc".  Then the content of the blob is set to something else.

```
function createNewBlob() {

  // Create an BLOB file with the content "abc"
  var blobNew = DriveApp.createFile('BlobTest', 'abc', MimeType.Blob);
  Logger.log(blobNew.getName());

  blobNew.setContent("Some new Content");
  Logger.log(blobNew.getBlob().getDataAsString())
};
```

You could create data in memory, then create the blob with the finished data.

Comment: This is the method. Make the file then set the content. A slight change to Sandy's suggestion would be that you can make an empty file and get the content as blob even though it is empty. Same method just a subtlety.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I was lost looking por new Blob() or something like that...