# Create json file and send it to someone with AppsScript

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

> I want to create a json file with some information and send it to some mail with AppsScript.

```
var objeto = {update:[]};
  var product = [];

  //starting loop
  for ( i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    product.push({
        id: i+1,
        name: "prueba"
    })
  }
  objeto.product = product;
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(objeto));
  //DriveApp.createFile('New Json File', JSON.stringify(objeto), MimeType.JSON );
```

> Some code here to create json file and send it to someone

Comment: Send it to someone… how?

Comment: with GmailApp. The main problem I have is how to create a json file (i already have json object builded)

Answer (score 1):

The [`createDraft`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#createdraftrecipient,-subject,-body,-options) method takes an `options` object as the 4th parameter.

One of the options is `attachments` which takes [an array of files](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob-source.html).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28386659/19068) explains how to convert a string to a Blob in Google Apps script. Do that, put it in an array, then pass it to `attachments`.

Comment: Do you know how the code will be? I have difficulties to understand it... thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function lfunko() {
  var objeto = { update: [] };
  var product = [];
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    product.push({
      id: i + 1,
      name: "prueba"
    })
  }
  objeto.product = product;
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(objeto));
  let f = DriveApp.createFile("name",JSON.stringify(objeto))
  GmailApp.sendEmail("your email","Test",JSON.stringify(objeto),{attachments:[f]});
}
```

Comment: I know this is a possible solution but I want to send a json file. Do you know how I can do it?